# How to get the log in reverse order with JGit?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm looking for the equivalent command in JGit for

```
git log --reverse
```

Can it be done by editing the config file for `git.log().all().call()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JGit's `LogCommand` does not allow to specify the order in which commits are listed.

The underlying `RevWalk`, however, can be used directly and allows to change the sort order, for example:

```java
RevWalk walk = new RevWalk( repository );
walk.sort( RevSort.COMMIT_TIME_DESC, true );
walk.sort( RevSort.REVERSE , true );
RevCommit commit = walk.next();
while( commit != null ) {
  // use commit
  commit = walk.next();
}
walk.close();
```